# Nitrogen dioxide vs Nitrogen peroxide: are they one and the same?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Are Nitogen Dioxide (NO2) & Nitrogen Peroxide (NO2) one & the same?

Comment: Welcome to the chemistry site of the StackExchange (SE) network.  Be aware that laconic, not elaborated questions are usually closed on the SE.  
The site expects that you include the compact summary of your related current knowledge, involving your conclusion of searching for existing related  info or answers. It would prevent others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself. Effort not shown may be considered as effort not done, possibly leading to the question closure. [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same. A compound is called peroxide when they contains the peroxide bond ($\ce{-O-O -}$). However, in this context, nitrogen peroxide can be considered an equilibrium mixture of nitrogen dioxide and dinitrogen tetroxide in varying proportions. The first mention of this "compound" was in this [1944 paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/153408a0), but not sure how accurate the information is in here considering an erratum has been published for this paper.

Comment: Yes I agree that a peroxide compund must have a peroxide bond (--O--O--) in it, but neither NO2 nor N2O4 has any. How it can still be called a Peroxide? Probably a dimer of N2O4 has --O--O-- bond in it.

Comment: @JagbirSinghKanet As I said, nitrogen peroxide is not an official term. It _can_ be considered the mixture of NO2 and N2O4 but it can add to more confusion as nitrogen peroxide in itself doesn't exist. Also, N2O4 doesn't have a dimer.